# Linked list string sorting issue

Tags: c++, string, sorting, linked-list

The problem is if I enter 1, then 2 and 123. It will sort 1,123,2.
How do i make it sort 1,2,123

Item is the Records that was created.
Runner is the traverser.

```
struct Records {
string Name;
string ID;
char Gender;
string Phone_Num;
Records *Next;
};

void SortRecords(Records* Item, Records* head, Records** Set_Head){
Records* Runner = head;

if (head == NULL){
    *Set_Head = Item;
}else if (Item->ID<head->ID){
    Item->Next=head;
}else{
    while(Item->ID>head->ID){
        if(Item->ID > Runner->ID && Runner->Next==NULL){
            Runner->Next=Item;
            break;
        }else if(Item->ID<Runner->Next->ID){
            Item->Next=Runner->Next;
            Runner->Next=Item;
            Runner=Item;
            cout<<Runner->Next->Name<<endl;
            break;
        }else{
            Runner=Runner->Next;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If `string` is really `std::string` then you're programming in C++ and should not use the C language tag.

Comment: That also explains the sorting problem you have, as strings when compared are compared *lexicographically*, where any string *beginning* with e.g. `'1'` will be smaller than any other string beginning with e.g. `'2'`.

Comment: Store your ID in an int or convert it into an int when doing the comparison. Look up how to parse strings into ints if you don't know how.

Comment: Please check the description of tags before applying them. The "c" tag explicitly tells you when it can be combined with "c++" and when not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::stoi` to compare integers not strings:

```
std::stoi(Item->ID) < std::stoi(Runner->Next->ID)
```

You might actually want to store ID as integer, not string.

If you ID can be, say "123AB", then you can extract number with:

```
string str = "123AB";
size_t last_index = str.find_last_of("0123456789");
string result = str.substr(0, last_index + 1); // result = "123";
```